# Hexadecimal Variables in substitution patterns

Tags: regex, perl

The file I am getting is full with badly formatted UTF-8 codes, like `<0308>` etc. I can identify them all right, but I want to replace them with the actual utf-8 letter, preferable with a regex. I've tried dozens of regexes like this:

```
s/<[0-9a-fA-F]{2,4}/\x{$1}/g
s/<[0-9a-fA-F]{2,4}/\N{U+$1}/g
```

And so on, but each time it tells me that `$` is not a valid hex-char (to which I fully agree). Shouldn't it just take the number in my `$1` and put it in there? Or does Perl really expect me to use `\x{..}` or `\N{U+..}` only with fixed values? If so, I'd have to hand-write the conversion for every possible hex-value - not very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one thing, you need to use parentheses to capture something in your regular expression; otherwise `$1` will not get set to anything.

`chr` + `hex` with eval will do the trick here:

```
s/ <
   ([0-9a-fA-F]{2,4})     # parentheses to set $1
   > 
 / 
   chr(hex($1)) 
 /gex;
```

Comment: Now I'd only need to know how to suppress the warning when dealing with utf chars with more than 1 Byte. But thanks, you helped me a lot. Am still a newb at Perl.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use the eval switch to it.  Try `/\x{$1}/eg` or `/"\x{$1}"/eg`

Comment: Nope, still getting the same "illegal $" error. And if I try `/"\\x{$1}"/eg` it writes exactly that, e.g. `\x{0308}` into my result file. And without the "'s, it tries to reference the sub `x`.

Answer (score 1):

What version of `perl` are you using?  This seems to work fine for me on 5.10.1:

```
$ perl -E '$foo = "<0308>"; $foo =~ s/<[0-9a-fA-F]{2,4}/\N{U+$1}/g; say $foo'
Wide character in print at -e line 1.
�>
```

(With `\x{$1}`, it seems to substitute the numbers with nothing, but I still don't get an error message.)

Comment: The resulted ? char is the same for every input in $foo, even with normal ASCII characters.

Comment: That's because you are not using parentheses to capture anything in the regular expression and `$1` is always zero.