# In Perl, why does variable interpolation fail for a hexadecimal escape sequence?

Tags: perl, escaping, character, sequence, interpolation

In Perl, if I run the code:

```
print "Literal Hex: \x{50} \n";
```

I get this: "`Literal Hex: P`"

However, if I run the code:

```
my $hex_num = 50; 
print "Interpolated Hex: \x{$hex_num}";
```

The variable does not interpolate properly and I get this: "`Interpolated Hex:`"

Similar failure results when I attempt to use variable interpolation in unicode and octal escape sequences.

Is it possible to use escape sequences (e.g. \x, \N) with interpolated string variables?  I was under the impression that a $variable contained within double quotes is always interpolated, but is this the exception?

*Note: Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118738/hexadecimal-variables-in-substitution-patterns), I am aware of the workaround: `chr(hex($hex_num))`, but my above questions regarding variable interpolation for escape sequences still stand.*

Comment: Consider: `my $n = 'n'; print "\$n";` It prints "$n", not a newline. The string is only going to be interpolated once.

Comment: Had to read the whole thing just to get to the workaround of...

    print(chr(hex($hex_num)));

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interpolation is not recursive, everything is interpolated just once, from left to right. Therefore, when `\x{$hex}` is being processed, the following applies (cited from [perlop](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators)):

> If there are no valid digits between the braces, the generated character is the NULL
>              character ("\x{00}").

Zero is really there:

```
perl -MO=Deparse -e '$h=50;print "<\x{$h}>"'
$h = 50;
print "<\000>";
-e syntax OK
```

Comment: Wow, thank you, answered perfectly! I don't know if I ever would have found this on my own.

Answer (score 1):

You should put in your variable the complete scape sequence:

```
my $hex_num = "\x50"; 
print "Interpolated Hex: $hex_num", "\n";
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but it doesn't get at the fundamental question I'm trying to answer here, which is why does "\x{$hex_num}" fail? Your answer relies on using a string literal, which works in one instance, but is not very practical for cycling $hex_num through every hex character from "\x001" to "\x501".

Comment: short answer: because there is not a double (2-phases) interpolation. There is only a single step

Comment: Interesting alternative, did not think of this.  Wouldn't fit my case, as I wanted a for-loop of integers and their sequences, but may be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

The issue I had was adding an escaped var into another variable such as:

```
$MYVAR = "20";
$myQuery = "\x02\x12\x10\x$MYVAR\x10";
```

Tried a number of \\x, \Q\x and various other escape sequences to no avail!!!

My workaround was not a direct escape but converting the var prior to adding to the string.

```
$MYVAR = chr(hex(20));
```

Did quite a bit of searching for a direct regex solution but had to run with this in the end.